# Python magic detects images just as 'binary'

Tags: python, django, mime-types

In another question here I've read that python-magic should output the correct mime type of a file. I've added `python-magic = 0.4.0` to my Django project, but here's what it detects:

```
In [2]: import magic
In [3]: m = magic.Magic(mime_encoding=True)
In [4]: m.from_file('/home/culebron/Documents/chapter2.pdf')
Out[4]: 'binary'

In [5]: m.from_file('/home/culebron/bok.jpg')
Out[5]: 'binary'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I need to distinguish between images and other binary file types, without relying on file extensions. So, I want to take a file content and in the end get an information that it is either jpeg, or png, or audio or something else. It may be python-magic, or suggest another module if you know.

I've tried `python-hachoir` from pypi, but its documentation state is appaling, and I couldn't find anything useful examining their modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [examples in the readme](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic#readme), it seems that you need to use `mime=True` instead of `mime_encoding=True` to get the mime type.